# JavaScript Best Practice Filtering Array By Three Factors

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, reduce

I'm filtering an array of Vet transactions per the following criteria:

- For each transaction within an hour only the most expensive transaction is placed in the result (transaction being {dog, timestamp, amount})
- If more than one transaction with the same dog ties for the most expensive transaction in a one hour period, only place the earliest transaction in the result
- If there are more than 10 transactions for a dog in the overall array of transactions, do not include any of the transactions from that dog in the result

An hour period is 00:00:00 - 00:59:59, 01:00:00 - 01:59:59, etc.

While keeping complexity down I'd like to come up with an easier to read solution that follows best practices. Here's the data (already sorted by time):

```
const dogs = [
  { "dog":"ralph", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 03:04:57", "amount": 140.00 },
  { "dog":"toto", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 03:14:31", "amount": 130.00 },
  { "dog":"toto", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 03:15:10", "amount": 145.00 },
  { "dog":"sadie", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 03:15:53", "amount": 175.00 },
  { "dog":"ralph", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 04:05:44", "amount": 220.00 },
  { "dog":"sadie", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 05:34:41", "amount": 100.00 },
  { "dog":"ralph", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 05:39:11", "amount": 40.00 },
  { "dog":"toto", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 05:43:00", "amount": 240.00 },
  { "dog":"toto", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 05:59:58", "amount": 235.00 },
  { "dog":"ralph", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 06:11:52", "amount": 20.00 },
  { "dog":"toto", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 06:12:53", "amount": 90.00 },
  { "dog":"rex", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 06:12:53", "amount": 315.00 },
  { "dog":"max", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 06:12:53", "amount": 285.00 },
  { "dog":"ralph", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 06:13:14", "amount": 240.00 },
  { "dog":"ralph", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 07:05:21", "amount": 60.00 },
  { "dog":"ralph", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 08:42:50", "amount": 80.00 },
  { "dog":"ralph", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 09:07:53", "amount": 100.00 },
  { "dog":"ralph", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 10:07:35", "amount": 200.00 },
  { "dog":"ralph", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 11:04:20", "amount": 120.00 },
  { "dog":"bella", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 11:04:40", "amount": 160.00 },
  { "dog":"sadie", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 11:04:54", "amount": 160.00 },
  { "dog":"bella", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 11:34:33", "amount": 160.00 },
  { "dog":"bella", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 11:44:23", "amount": 160.00 },
  { "dog":"bella", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 11:48:43", "amount": 125.00 },
  { "dog":"bella", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 12:03:53", "amount": 80.00 },
  { "dog":"bella", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 12:04:03", "amount": 100.00 },
  { "dog":"bella", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 13:11:54", "amount": 125.00 },
  { "dog":"ralph", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 14:04:35", "amount": 160.00 },
  { "dog":"bella", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 14:21:10", "amount": 170.00 },
  { "dog":"bella", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 15:15:18", "amount": 140.00 },
  { "dog":"bella", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 16:15:20", "amount": 180.00 },
  { "dog":"ralph", "timestamp":"2/23/2020 17:49:55", "amount": 180.00 }
]
```

Here's my working solution:

```
function lessThanTen(dogs) {
  let count = {}
  let results = [];
  for(let i = 0; i<dogs.length; i++) {
    count[dogs[i].dog] ? count[dogs[i].dog] +=1 : count[dogs[i].dog] = 1;
  }
  for(let i = 0; i<dogs.length; i++) {
    if(!(count[dogs[i].dog] > 10)) {
      results.push(dogs[i]);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

function mostExpensive(dogs) {
  let curHour, nextHour, prevAmount, curAmount, nextAmount, highIndex;
  let results = [];
  const filtered = lessThanTen(dogs);

  filtered.forEach((click, index) => {
    curHour = filtered[index].timestamp.split(" ")[1].substring(0,2);
    curAmount = filtered[index].amount;
    if(index > 0) {
      prevAmount = filtered[index-1].amount;
    }
    if(index < filtered.length - 1) {
      nextHour = filtered[index + 1].timestamp.split(" ")[1].substring(0,2);
      nextAmount = filtered[index + 1].amount
    }
    if ((curHour === nextHour) && ((curAmount > prevAmount && curAmount > nextAmount) || (curAmount === nextAmount && !highIndex)) ) {
      highIndex = index;
    }
    if (nextHour > curHour) {
      results.push(filtered[highIndex ? highIndex : index]);
      highIndex = null;
    }
  });
  console.log(results);
}
mostExpensive(dogs);
```

Can / should I break out the "if more than one transaction for the same dog in an hour period" into it's own function so it's easier to test?

Is there a good way to clean up all the if statements in the forEach? I took a stab at filter and reduce but unfortunately got lost with comparing previous and current amounts and times.

For the less than ten function, should I use something other than for loops? Whats the best practice here? I couldn't think of a way to avoid using two loops O(2n). Suggestions?

Generally, whats the most legible, functional way to accomplish the three criteria?

Comment: The second critera seems unclear to me. By "for each dog seen within an hour" do you mean "for each transaction within an hour" or "for each transaction regarding a specific dog within an hour"? The second part of the condition seems to contradict the first part. The earliest transaction for a dog might not be the most expensive transaction for that dog.

I spotted a bug in the lessThanTen function. It should have `>= 10` rather than `> 10`.

Comment: When I run the code with the correcton, Bella is omitted and I get a result with only three transactions. I expected a transaction for every hour period, what is the correct result supposed to look like?

Comment: Thank you Guffa, - the three criteria are:
For each transaction within an hour only the most expensive transaction is placed in the result
If more than one transaction with the same dog ties for the most expensive transaction in a one hour period, only place the earliest transaction in the result
If there are more than 10 transactions for a dog in the overall array of transactions, do not include any of the transactions from that dog in the result

(because its more than, the >10 is intentional)

Comment: The correct result should be:
[ { dog: 'sadie', timestamp: '2/23/2020 03:15:53', amount: 175 },
  { dog: 'toto', timestamp: '2/23/2020 05:43:00', amount: 240 },
  { dog: 'rex', timestamp: '2/23/2020 06:12:53', amount: 315 },
  { dog: 'bella', timestamp: '2/23/2020 11:04:40', amount: 160 },
  { dog: 'bella', timestamp: '2/23/2020 12:04:03', amount: 100 },
  { dog: 'bella', timestamp: '2/23/2020 13:11:54', amount: 125 },
  { dog: 'bella', timestamp: '2/23/2020 14:21:10', amount: 170 },
  { dog: 'bella', timestamp: '2/23/2020 15:15:18', amount: 140 } ]

Comment: Thanks, that's clearer, and the expected result is really useful. Why shouldn't the transaction from `16:15:20` be in the result?  I can't see that it's excluded by any of the criteria.

Comment: Good catch Guffa, thank you - yes the transaction from 16:15:20 should be in the result and I missed that. 

My solution also wasn't accounting for edge cases I'm noticing - like if there is only one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

#### lessThanTen

You are misusing a conditional operator to work as an if statement. Written out (and using the `in` operator to check if the dog is in the `count` collection), that would instead be:

```
if (dogs[i].dog in count) {
  count[dogs[i].dog] += 1;
} else {
  count[dogs[i].dog] = 1;
}
```

That is clearer, but it can be made less repetetive. You can use the conditional operator as an actual operator to check if there is an existing value. Getting the dog name in a local variable makes the code shorter and more readable:

```
let dog = dogs[i].dog;
count[dog] = (dog in count ? count[dog] : 0) + 1;
```

Instead of adding items to `results` in a loop, you can use the `filter` method of the array to get the items where the dog occurs ten times or less:

```
dogs.filter(item => count[item.dog] <= 10)
```

That would make the function:

```
function lessThanTen(dogs) {
  let count = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < dogs.length; i++) {
    let dog = dogs[i].dog;
    count[dog] = (dog in count ? count[dog] : 0) + 1;
  }
  return dogs.filter(item => count[item.dog] <= 10);
}
```

#### mostExpensive

I couldn't really follow the intention in the code. It seems that you are comparing each item with the previous and the next, but that doesn't tell you if it's the highest within the hour. Also, comparing with the previous amount when that might be from a different hour seems like an error.

I rewrote the function with an algorithm that I hope is easy to follow. It just keeps the index of the best item that it finds by comparing with the previously best item. As there is no look ahead, you will have the best item from the last hour to add to the result after the loop.

```
function mostExpensive(dogs) {
  const filtered = lessThanTen(dogs);

  let results = [];
  let prevHour = null, highIndex = null;

  filtered.forEach((item, index) => {
    let hour = item.timestamp.split(" ")[1].substring(0,2);
    // When the hour changes
    if (prevHour !== null && hour !== prevHour) {
      // Add best item found in previous hour
      results.push(filtered[highIndex]);
      // Reset index for the new hour
      highIndex = null;
    }
    // When first item in hour, or better than previously found
    if (highIndex === null || item.amount > filtered[highIndex].amount) {
      // Keep the index of the best item
      highIndex = index;
    }
    // Keep the hour for next iteration
    prevHour = hour;

  });
  // If there is a result from the last hour
  if (highIndex !== null) {
    // Add best item found in last hour
    results.push(filtered[highIndex]);
  }
  console.log(results);
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for walking through the lessThanTen function Guffa!

Comment: @T.Selleck: I added a rewrite of the `mostExpensive` function.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for commenting through Guffa!